# How to retrieve the current input in a paper-dropdown-menu

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, polymer-elements

I have the following snippets of a paper-dropdown-menu

### .dart

....

```
@property
List<String> suffixes = <String>[
  'I',
  'II',
  'III',
  'Junior',
  'Senior'
];
```

### .html

```
<paper-dropdown-menu label = "Suffix">
  <paper-menu class = "dropdown-content">
    <template is = "dom-repeat"
              items = "[[suffixes]]"
              as = "suffix">
      <paper-item>[[suffix]]</paper-item>
    </template>
  </paper-menu>
</paper-dropdown-menu>
```

What is the correct .dart code to get the selection made in the dropdown?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve this.
The example below shows two ways using `selected-item` and `selected-item-label`

**.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<dom-module id='app-element'>
  <template>
    <paper-dropdown-menu label = "Suffix"
                         selected-item="{{selectedItem}}">
      <paper-menu class = "dropdown-content">
        <template id="ddmtr" is="dom-repeat"
                  items="[[suffixes]]"
                  as="suffix">
          <paper-item label="suffix">[[suffix]]</paper-item>
        </template>
      </paper-menu>
    </paper-dropdown-menu>
    <div>selectedItem:<span>[[selectedItem]]</span> value: <span>[[selectedItemValue]]</span></div>

    <paper-dropdown-menu label = "Suffix"
                         selected-item-label="{{selectedItemLabel}}">
      <paper-menu class = "dropdown-content">
        <template is="dom-repeat"
                  items="[[suffixes]]"
                  as="suffix">
          <paper-item>[[suffix]]</paper-item>
          <!-- <paper-item label="suffix">[[suffix]]</paper-item> -->
          <!-- if the label attribute is not set, the text content is used -->
        </template>
      </paper-menu>
    </paper-dropdown-menu>
    <div>selectedItemLabel:<span>[[selectedItemLabel]]</span></div>
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

**.dart**

```
@HtmlImport('app_element.html')
library so33770938_paper_dropdown_menu_selected.web.app_element;

import 'dart:html' as dom;
import 'package:web_components/web_components.dart' show HtmlImport;
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
import 'package:polymer_elements/paper_dropdown_menu.dart';
import 'package:polymer_elements/paper_menu.dart';
import 'package:polymer_elements/paper_item.dart';

/// [PaperDropdownMenu], [PaperMenu], [PaperItem]
@PolymerRegister('app-element')
class AppElement extends PolymerElement {
  AppElement.created() : super.created();

  @property var selectedItem;

  @property var selectedItemLabel;

  @Property(computed: 'getSelectedItemValue(selectedItem)')
  String selectedItemValue;

  @reflectable
  String getSelectedItemValue(dom.Element selectedItem) {
    DomRepeatModel model =
        ($['ddmtr'] as DomRepeat).modelForElement(selectedItem);
    return suffixes[model.index];
  }

  @property
  List<String> suffixes = <String>[
    'I',
    'II',
    'III',
    'Junior',
    'Senior'
  ];
}
```

Comment: Thanks Gunter. An observation of the dropdown produced for suffix using the code demonstrates something quite quirky. Each time I clicked an item in the dropdown, the number of items seen on the next click of the dropdown is reduced until only horizontal and vertical scroll arrows are seen. Have you ever seen this?

Comment: This is a known issue. I hope this gets fixed with the next update to the newest JS element (already work in progress).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.